# How to solve the permission denied problem, when editing a file created inside a docker container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, permissions, containers

I'm a student, I know javascript and react, I'm starting to study docker.
I have a small problem. Create a docker-compose to create the container based on the node:16-alpine image with stdin_open and tty set to TRUE.
I accessed the container, and inside I created a react app with npx create-react-app, everything worked, but when editing the files directly from my machine (and not inside the container), I get the error message EACCES: permission denied.

When trying to create a file inside the react app folder, already created inside the container, the error that I don't have permission for such action is displayed.

Meu docker-compose.yml está assim:

```
version: '3'
services:
  front-end:
    image: node:16-alpine
    container_name: rest_front_end
    working_dir: /auto-rest
    volumes:
      - ./front-end:/auto-rest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: sh
    ports:
      - 30001:3000
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: The files were probably created without your user in mind. Manually change the permissions to the files to something that both you and Docker can access and you'll be golden.

Comment: In typical use I'd expect to see a Dockerfile that packages your application into a reusable image.  You shouldn't need `volumes:` to inject the application code, `working_dir:`, or `command:` in the Compose setup; all of this should be included in the Dockerfile.  The Docker [Containerize an application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial has one routine sample.

Comment: (If you want to run the application code that's on your host system without using Docker's image system, you don't need Docker for this; just run Node directly.  It'd be very reasonable to develop and unit-test your application using non-container tools even if you're going to eventually use immutable images for deployment.)